# Open string in app per drag'n'drop on icon

Tags: cocoa

My idea:
I select a string/text and drop it on my app's icon.
My app comes up and does fancy things with the string.

Now my question is how I can do it that I can drop it on the app, how I can notify my app and how my app gets the string.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you have already looked at official [Drag and Drop Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html) .

There is a blog article dealing exactly with your issue: [Cocoa Drag and Drop text into the Dock Icon](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/aug/06/cocoa-drag-and-drop-text-into-the-dock-icon/).